# Python GCD program

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm, python-2.7

```
def gcd(m,n):
    
   fm = []
   for i in range(1, m+1):
       if (m%i) == 0 :
           fm.append(i)
           
   fn = []
   for j in range(1, n+1):
       if (n%j) == 0 :
           fm.append(j)
           
   cf = []
   for f in fm:
       if f in fn:
           cf.append(f)
           
   return(cf[-1])
   
print(gcd(56,23))
```

---

Although, there are other ways to find gcd using while loop and math.gcd commands, but my mentor wants this solution working as its mentioned in his programming book. How can I solve IndexError: list index out of range in the above program.

Comment: Maybe check if cf has any elements before trying to access them? `return cf[-1] if cf else None`

Comment: Start debugging the program. Post your findings.

Answer (score 3):

You don't append anything to cf.

In your 2nd for loop, change `fm.append(j)` to `fn.append(j)`

Comment: thanks, for catching with typo :)